# Same executable with different icons

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-3, okular

I want to open a pdf-viewer (`okular`) with different icons from the gnome-console.

Basically I want to differentiate between `pdfs` I am reading. Some would have the default `okular` icon, but I would like to have a different/special icon for the `pdf` generated by the `LaTeX` document I am editing.

Thinking about how to do this, I realized that I am not sure how `gnome` knows what icon to use when I execute `/usr/bin/okular` from the console. How is that bin related with an icon, no `.desktop` file involved right?

Comment: When you mention icon, you're referring to the application icon in the top bar and/or the running-applications panel in the Overview, right? Not the file-browser icon for the files themselves?

Comment: Yes, the first one, the icon that appears when alt-tab between applications.  Not the file-browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications set their icon at launch, to a compiled-in value. Most do it using the API of their graphics toolkit (Gtk provides various forms of the [`gtk_window_set_icon`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-icon) API call), but it has its roots in an X Windows window-manager property that's as old as dirt — which is why, for example, `okular` still has an application icon in Gnome Shell even though it's a KDE application.

You can see a grayscale representation of the icon(s) an application is exporting if you type `xprop` in a terminal, then click the application's window. (You need to have the correct utilities package installed, it's called `xorg-x11-utils` in Fedora.)

The application icon doesn't depend on Gnome or on the `.desktop` file under any circumstances.

(In fact, you *could* create your own `$HOME/.local/share/applications/okular.desktop` file that represented the application with a different icon, and launch it by clicking that icon, but it would be ignored in favor of the one that's compiled in to the application once it started. I have some custom launchers in my Favorites panel for different VNC sessions, using a different icon for each, but they all show up as TigerVNC with the standard icon when launched.)

AFAIK the only way to do what you want would be to compile your own separate version of `okular` with the icon changed to something else. That's just not the way application icons were meant to be used, sorry.

Comment: I should note, as a final additional wrinkle, that many applications set their icon to the _name_ of an installed icon, rather than setting it directly to a particular image, as that allows the icon to be themed. So, an application _can_ have a different icon depending on the selected theme. But there's still a 1:1 relationship between application and icon — a theme can change the icon for _all_ instances of the application, but not just some of them.